# Godot 3.0 Change Animation of KinimaticBody 2D following a path

Tags: isometric, godot, path-2d

I'm trying to get a kinematic body to change its animation to the appropriate isometric one as it follows a path. The code I'm using is below and it is attached to A KinematicBody2D. Any idea would be helpful even changes to structure etc.

```
Game
--TileMap
----Pathe2D
------PatheFollow2D
--------KinematicBody2D
--------CollisionShape2D
--------AnimationSprite
```

The Code Currently

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var direction = Vector2()
var currentdirection = Vector2(0,0)

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    set_physics_process(true)

func _physics_process(delta):
    var dir = position
    var direction = dir.normalized()
    print(position)

    ghost_anim(dir)
    # Moves Ghost
    get_parent().set_offset(get_parent().get_offset() + 250 * delta)


func ghost_anim(direction):
    var spritedir
    if currentdirection != direction:
        if currentdirection == Vector2(-1,-1):
            spritedir = "Back_Left"
        elif currentdirection == Vector2(1,-1):
            spritedir = "Back_Right"  
        elif direction == Vector2(-1,1):  
            spritedir = "Front_Left"
        elif direction == Vector2(1,1):  
            spritedir = "Front_Right"
        else:
            pass
    else:
        spritedir = "Front_Left"

    get_node("Ghost").set_animation(spritedir)

    currentdirection = direction
    return currentdirection
```

Comment: I don't think I completely follow. Do you have any image so we can visualize your current issue vs the expected result?